Community Polls Thread
Welcome to the RE.SE Community Poll thread!
Note: Order answers by active to see the most recent polls.
This thread is used for opinion and usage polls around RE and RE.SE.
The poll questions are added as "answers" to this "question". Their answers are added as comments below them. To participate simply up-vote the comments which apply for you. If there is no suitable answer yet simply add it as a comment yourself. You can't up-vote your own comments but the comment author will be counted manually. Please do not add any other comments to these posts. General comments can be added to this "question".
Rules

Community poll questions are placed as "answer" posts below. Feel free to add your own. Use dummy text, in case of yes/no answers.
Answers to these poll questions are placed as "comments" below them. Because this is also an opinion poll subjective questions are welcome.
Please do not ask too specific questions and allow for multiple choices and votes, e.g. instead of something like "My absolute favorite for X is .." use something like "For X I often use ...".
To participate up-vote the comments which apply for you.
If required add a new answer as a comment.
If applicable hyperlink the entry to allow other users to learn more about it. Feel free to flag comments for moderator attention if they should be modified for some valid reason (wrong/missing hyperlink, etc.)
Feel free to up-vote the poll questions ("answer" posts) as well to indicate that you liked the question. This will push the most favorite questions to the top.
Do not post any other answer posts or comments. Please provide feedback and critique on the corresponding discussion thread if it exists, or on a new thread instead.
Do not start polls about site policies here. Start them in a separate thread to get them the necessary attention.


 Post taken from Tex.Se  

Poll Question:
I heard about the RE SE though...

Reddit (DUMMYFOOBARFILLER)

Area 51 (.....)

Stack Exchange Podcast #47

Sample Poll
My skill level in RE is ...
Upvote the comment that best describes you

Beginner (Comment limit)

Intermediate (Comment limit)

Advanced (Comment limit)

Has RE.SE improved as compared to a 100 days ago?

Most questions are very Googlable and there are not that much questions. Although most questions get answers within the hour. I'd say, it has improved, but it does really need a lot more members (with questions).

FWIW: http://meta.reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/252/lets-get-critical-aug-2013-site-self-evaluation - there'll be another one of these kicking off in a few weeks, and it's an excellent opportunity to share your thoughts on the site's progress and overall quality...
